# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook with bulit in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I am able to Access Outlook Mails files through Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook if Outlook is installed as a separate Program.

However Windows 10 does have a built in Outlook running the Application Framehost. I am not able to connect to it in any way.

This is how I can access outlook

```
var ol = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
var windowType = ol.Application.ActiveWindow();
```

The Exe of the Built in Outlook is called HxOutlook.exe

Is there any way to tell c# that I want to access HxOutlook.exe?

Comment: That is the Windows 10 Mail app. Despite the name, it is nothing to do with Outlook.

Comment: The Windows 10 mail app isn't Outlook and does not support automation. Outlook is part of MS Office, not Windows. If you don't have Outlook installed as part of Office, you can't use 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' (it has **.Office.** in the name for a reason).